# Sending Notification between Emulators

Tags: java, android, eclipse

As already asked by one person I would like to know, if someone could help us in Sending and recieving notification between 2 emulators.
For example there is a function which sends notification, but not to the same emulator (say 5554) but to another emulator (say 5556) so that receiver could check the notification and trigger the `onClick listener` to accept or reject the Notification

```
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,msg,System.currentTimeMillis());
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, msg, details, null);
int num = 0;
manager.notify(num, notification);
```

Comment: first Notification != SMS ... next: you can intercept SMS ... you can also use GCM to sending messages to android device ... you can build your own service for doing this ... you can use socket(fx: udp) to comunicate between devices ...

Comment: Thanks for the first reply are u sure that using GCM could send a notification which will show options like accept or decline which triggers an onclick listener .???

Comment: If you write an application which gets the notification and then displays it as such, sure.

Comment: OK, I could not get with references which sends notification between two emulators rather it could send only to the same device

Answer (score 1):

Notification cant be sent to another device, you can only notify your own device by your app. if you want to show any notification in another device you have to write codes for it in your app which runs on the other device and trigger the notification using sms or some web service or the push mesassage system.

if you want to communicate with other device for notification.. use the PUSHMESSAGE.. check GCM http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: thnk u i hope it would be helpful !! :) :)